# how to refference button with specific id inside a contentPlaceholder

Tags: html, css

Do I have to refference an Id such as ctl00$MainContent$send or can I somehow specify asp.bet that I want it to keep the id as simple as send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose whatever ID you want, as long as it **doesn't exist anywhere else in the page**.